# Splitting a spot swap into a forward swap and a 3 month libor

Tags: interest-rate-swap, forward-rate, libor

I read the following statement:

> We can construct a 5 year swap using 3 month libor combined with a 3mo-4.75yr forward swap, weighted by the dv01s of each part.

I am not sure I understand how this is the case.

Can someone please explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I think they're saying [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35795/)...

The USD market convention is that the floating leg pays quarterly and is set at the beginning of the coupon period from 3mo libor, and the fixed leg pays semi-annually.

You can view a vanilla 5-year swap as a portfolio of two instruments with the same notional as the original swap: the first floating coupon, which is already set to 3mo libor, and all the remaining coupons, which start in 3 months and last for 4 years and 9 months. Note that the first fixed coupon still pays 6 months of accrual.

(I don't see the relevance of the dv01.)